# Not able to add or modify tags in specflow 2.1.0

Tags: specflow

I am not able to add or modify tag in specflow 2.1.0. I am using VS2015 with Update 3.

Thanks,
Rina

Comment: Why are you not able to add/modify tags? What is happening if you try to do it?

Comment: Lots of build error are coming in feature.cs file

Comment: Are they similar to this: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/issues/1206